# Reducer not firing due to duplicate "feature keys": further mitigation

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I'm using Angular 7 with redux.  My state is generated using [ngrx](https://ngrx.io/guide/store) and as we are using a mono-repository, the whole thing is managed using [Nrwl](https://blog.nrwl.io/nrwl-nx-an-open-source-toolkit-for-enterprise-angular-applications-38698e94d65).

I recently encountered an issue where my reducer was not being called at all.  My unit tests all worked fine, but when I ran the application the reducer was simply never called and there were no errors reported in the application.  After running through some process-of-elimination steps I was able to fix the issue by changing the "Feature Key" for the state.  I.e. I went from:

```
export const SEARCH_FEATURE_KEY = 'search';
```

To:

```
export const SEARCH_FEATURE_KEY = 'omnisearch';
```

It took me a couple hours to identify this fix, which is never fun.  After I figured out how to fix the problem, I did some more searching in my code base and finally found the other module that was using the `search` feature key.  Naturally, it was in some old code that was no longer being used (and is now removed from the code base), and which had declared its feature key in a non-standard way, making it harder for me to find it in the code base.  We have much better consistency these days, but (like many) have some older code still laying around waiting to cause trouble.

Obviously it would have saved me a lot of trouble if the `ngrx` bindings we use had issued an error about duplicate feature keys instead of just silently ignoring one of the reducers.  In a large enough application, mistakes like this are inevitable, and I'm trying to figure out if there are any further steps I can take (other than changing naming conventions) to make debugging mistakes like this quicker in the future.  Does `ngrx` have any debugging modes that I might have missed?  Is there a log file hiding somewhere that I don't know about which may have told me what was going on?  Or is this just a case where opening an issue with `ngrx` may be the best way forward?